# This site can’t provide a secure connection ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, cloud, linode

i am trying to open my website abc.members.linode.com:80.

but i got this error :`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

i am using linode and i have a certificate for ssl for this domain :

```
https://abc.members.linode.com
```

But i am not sure why i got `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

My config into  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name https://abc.members.linode.com abc.members.linode.com;
        root /var/www/abc.members.linode.com;
        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html index.php;
        }
}
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to open my website abc.members.linode.com:80.
>
> but i got this error :ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

There is no SSL configured for this site. You are trying to access a plain HTTP site (no encryption) with HTTPS (encryption expected). This will not work and that's why you get this error.

> ```
>     server_name https://abc.members.linode.com abc.members.linode.com;
> ```

The server_name should be the hostname(s) of the server, not a URL like `https://...`.